# RxBluetoothKit - implement read and write protocol and automatically disconnect

Tags: core-bluetooth, rx-swift, rxiosble

I'm implementing a BLE protocol between a central (iPhone) and peripheral (custom device). The protocol works as follows:

1. central connects to peripheral and sets up notification
2. peripheral sends data on notification characteristic
3. central processes data and sends response on separate characteristic
4. peripheral sends addtnl data on notification characteristic
5. central process data and disconnects.

I'm attempting to implement this in a clean way using RxBluetoothKit. It currently works, but I'd like to solve the following challenges:

1. What is the best way to cleanly disconnect in step 5. I'm hoping to not have to dispose the overall observable, but rather just have it 'complete'. I'm currently using 'takeUntil', but not sure if that's the best way.
2. Allow for the notification to cleanup gracefully prior to disconnect. With my current code, I receive an 'API MISUSE can only accept commands while in the connected state' because I believe the notification is cleaning up while the disconnect is occurring.

Thanks.

```swift
enum TestPeripheralService: String, ServiceIdentifier {

    case main = "CED916FA-6692-4A12-87D5-6F2764762B23"

    var uuid: CBUUID { return CBUUID(string: self.rawValue) }
}

enum TestPeripheralCharacteristic: String, CharacteristicIdentifier {

    case writer = "CED927B4-6692-4A12-87D5-6F2764762B2A"
    case reader = "CED9D5D8-6692-4A12-87D5-6F2764762B2A"

    var uuid: CBUUID { return CBUUID(string: self.rawValue) }

    var service: ServiceIdentifier { return TestPeripheralService.main }
}

fileprivate lazy var centralManager: CentralManager = {
    RxBluetoothKitLog.setLogLevel(.verbose)
    return CentralManager(queue: .main)
}()

func executeConnectionAndHandshake() {

    let disconnectSubject = PublishSubject<Bool>.init()
    var peripheral: Peripheral?
    var packetNum = 0
    _ = centralManager
        .observeState()
        .startWith(centralManager.state)
        .filter { $0 == .poweredOn }
        .flatMap { _ in self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [TestPeripheralService.main.uuid]) }
        .flatMap { $0.peripheral.establishConnection().takeUntil(disconnectSubject) }
        .do(onNext: { peripheral = $0 })
        .flatMap { $0.discoverServices([TestPeripheralService.main.uuid])}
        .flatMap { $0[0].discoverCharacteristics(nil)}
        .flatMap { _ in

            Observable<Bool>.create { event in

                let disposables = CompositeDisposable()
                let readSubject = PublishSubject<Data>.init()
                _ = disposables.insert(peripheral!.observeValueUpdateAndSetNotification(for: TestPeripheralCharacteristic.reader)
                    .subscribe(onNext: {
                        packetNum += 1
                        let packet = $0.value!
                        if (packetNum <= 1) {
                            readSubject.onNext(packet)
                        } else {
                            event.onNext(true)
                            event.onCompleted()
                        }

                    }, onError: { event.onError($0) })
                )

                _ = disposables.insert(readSubject
                    .flatMapLatest { data -> Single<Characteristic> in
                        var writeData = Data(capacity: 300)
                        for _ in 0..<300 {
                            writeData.append(0xFF)
                        }
                        return peripheral!.writeValue(writeData, for: TestPeripheralCharacteristic.writer, type: .withResponse)
                    }
                    .subscribe(onError: { event.onError($0) })
                )

                return Disposables.create {
                    disposables.dispose()
                }
            }
            .do(onCompleted: { disconnectSubject.onNext(true) })
        }
        .subscribe(onError: { print($0) },
                   onCompleted: { print("Connection and handshake completed") })
}
```